# click button sevral times make the game run faster and faster - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, setinterval, requestanimationframe

As part of my studies I build the game "Space Invaders" in javascript by using canvas.
Before the beginning of the game, the main page is loaded and waiting to click on new game button. When i clicked on this button, the game begins to run properly and there are no problems at all. (the game runs through a recursive function that call to functions update() and render() -see code-...)
The problem comes when during the run of the game i push this button again. What happens is that the game run faster and when i clicked on it several times the game run faster and faster...

i dont now if its because the cycle of interval was not clear itself or maybe its because run() function call itself again and cause to loop into the recursive functions.

thanks a lot.

//----------------------------------------//
//this function called when i pressed in newGame button

```
    function startGame()
    {   
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
        run();
        // run function - run the recursive function below
        timeInterval = setInterval(randEnemyShots,frequencyShot);
        // randEnemyShots function - choose one enemey from all enemies to shot 
        // frequencyShot variable - this is the frequqncy of shots 
    }
```

//----------------------------------------//

```
    function run()
    {
        var loop=function(){
            if(gameRuning)
            {
                update(); 
                // update function - all the logic of game
                render();
                // render function - drawing the game 
                window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
            }
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
    }
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Comment: Its not a bug it is feature, change "Start Game" to "Difficulty increase".=)

Comment: i thought about it too but i save it to plan B ;)

Comment: But if seriously can you provide full script? What is a scope of those variables? timeInterval, gameRunning?

Comment: May be moving var loop to global scope will fix thing, coz then you can reassign it.

Comment: @maximelian1986.. game running it a boolean variable that if the player still alive the game keep running ... timeInterval its just variable to clear the cycle of interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you click the 'Start' button you are calling the `run()` function again which is effectively doubling the speed of the game.

The `run()` function should be called only once in the game initialisation so that the game loop can run indefinitely.

```
function gameInit(){
    //Initialisation code here
    run(); //Start the game loop only once
}

function startGame() {   
    //Handle 'Start' button click
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
    timeInterval = setInterval(randEnemyShots,frequencyShot);
}
```

You can then use the `gameRuning` value to 'pause' the loop if you set to false.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you used setTimeout (with checking) rather than setInterval. Since the behaviour and cost of setInterval usually weird.